# llvm no optimization for certain instructions

Tags: llvm

I am inserting some instructions into llvm IR to do some Integer Overflow(IO) checking. However, I am annoyed to find some of my instructions inserted get optimized by the optimizer.

For example, when there is

```
int result = data + 1;
```

My pass would see this operation as a potential overflow site and add(IR of course, I wrote C here to make my life easier):

```
int64_t result_64bit = (int64_t)data + 1
if (result_64bit > 2147483647) { report(); }
```

However,  this instruction gets optimized out.

Here's what I tried:

add -O0 flag. It won't work. I have dumped IR after every pass and that happened on pass Remove redundant operation. (Not Redundant from my perspective...)

Move the pass to the end of optimization by setting EP_OptimizerLast flag.
Well, this is not optimal as some information gets lost. For example, I heavily rely on nsw/nuw flag to decide signs, some of these flags gets removed after optimizations.

So what I am asking is if there is some kind of instruction guard in LLVM that guards an instruction against been optimized or removed?

Comment: Just a short question, do you dump your generated LLVM IR to file and then use clang on that file?

Comment: Hi JKRT:) No I didn't. I did dump IR to see what's what, but I never stop the compilation. I compiled twice, first compilation to dump IR, second to binary. Why ask? Does that have some unknown effect?

Comment: Ok. No just interested. Still can't you just remove all passes from the pass manager and just run your own pass before?

Comment: So what you do is maybe generate LLVM IR from C loading the IR. Using some analysis on it, inserting your instructions dumping it. After that do you run it through Clang?

Comment: Yeah, you can say that

Comment: I assume you know about `-fwrapv` and are enabling something like that to make the result well-defined?  Or you could probably use the same hooks that clang's `__builtin_add_overflow` uses: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#checked-arithmetic-builtins (GCC 5.0 and later also has it: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integer-Overflow-Builtins.html

Comment: Hi Peter. Thanks for the insight, I learnt about `-fwrapv` later in this project. If you can put it in the answer I'll give you a thumb up :) Really appreciate it.